# When does NVDA announce "alert unavailable"?

Tags: wai-aria, nvda

I am clicking on a select button. A slider opens but the NVDA announces "alert unavailable" .Why does it announce that?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: I am using an application which is made of many files of code. I am not able to find which particular file is responsible for that announcement.